# Autosave annotations when using PDFnet in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, pdfnet

Im using [Pdfnet](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/) on a windows 8.1 project, i would like to know if there is a way to do a autosave when user inserts or removes a annotation (ink, highlight, etc...), or at least detect when a annotation is added to the document ( i can do the save then )

**Edit:**

I managed to do a kind of autosave using

```
_ViewModel.PDFViewCtrl.GetAnnotationCanvas().ManipulationCompleted += MainPage_ManipulationCompleted;
```

and in that event i save the document everytime its triggered, works for well except for "note" annotations, that dont trigger the event when inserted.

Comment: Are you using the PDFViewCtrlTools project to handle adding annotations?

If so, you can register for ToolManager's AnnotationAdded, AnnotationEdited, and AnnotationRemoved events.

Comment: i have this variable 
anBar = new pdftron.PDF.Tools.Controls.AnnotationToolbar();

Comment: then when i do anBar.ToolManager.AnnotationAdded += ToolManager_AnnotationAdded , the event trigger on note, highlight and erase, but it doesnt trigger on ink ( these are the 4 options i have no my toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating the ToolManager yourself, and then setting the Annotation Toolbar's toolmanager.

```
ToolManager toolManager = new ToolManager(myPDFViewCtrl).
anBar.ToolManager = toolManager;
toolManager.AnnotationAdded += ToolManager_AnnotationAdded;
```

Finally, since all this code is open source, I would recommend just sticking a breakpoint in the CommitAnnotation function in FreeHandCreate. Follow the execution, and see what might be going wrong.